# Linking Qt DLL to Qt App - unresolved references

Tags: qt, dll, qt4, dllimport, unresolved-external

I've just installed Qt 4.7.4 and trying to make a simple Qt App that uses Qt DLL. I added export/import in a class in DLL through ifdef as usual but when compiling App I het unresolved references. I also set that App depends on the DLL.

Here are the main files:

---

Lib.pro

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Lib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += LIB_LIBRARY

SOURCES += lib.cpp

HEADERS += lib.h\
        Lib_global.h

symbian {
    MMP_RULES += EXPORTUNFROZEN
    TARGET.UID3 = 0xE10C4E25
    TARGET.CAPABILITY = 
    TARGET.EPOCALLOWDLLDATA = 1
    addFiles.sources = Lib.dll
    addFiles.path = !:/sys/bin
    DEPLOYMENT += addFiles
}

unix:!symbian {
    maemo5 {
        target.path = /opt/usr/lib
    } else {
        target.path = /usr/lib
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

---

App.pro

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = App
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

---

lib.h

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

#include "Lib_global.h"
#include <QString>

class LIBSHARED_EXPORT Lib {
public:
    Lib();
    ~Lib();
    QString Hello(QString a);
};

#endif // LIB_H
```

---

Lib_global.h

```
#ifndef LIB_GLOBAL_H
#define LIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(LIB_LIBRARY)
#  define LIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define LIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // LIB_GLOBAL_H
```

What's wrong with this code? Why is it unresolved reference?
In App I just include "../Lib/lib.h" and try to use the class.

Answer (score 1):

What looks to be missing is the link between your application and your dynamic library.

I usually do something like this for my desktop (linux) apps:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  ./include
LIBS += -L./lib -lLib
```

Where:

**INCLUDEPATH** defines the path to where your shared library .h files are located.

**LIBS** defines the path to where your built library is.

You can find the relevant documentation here: [QMake - Declaring Other Libraries](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries)

**Updated:**

I was able to build the project (Linux Qt v4.7.4) and link to the library using the code you posted. I will try to clarify as my response may not be entirely clear.

The **INCLUDEPATH** and **LIBS** variables must be added to the App.pro file.
For the linker to properly find the library the paths must be adjusted to the paths you are using for your project:

LIBS += -L **PATH** -l **LIBNAME**

Supposing your folder structure is similar to the following:

```
Project
    |_ Lib (your sharded library project files)
    |_ App (your application project files)
```

You would adjust the variables like so:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  ../Lib
LIBS += -L../Lib -lLib
```

Note that you link differently depending on your platform, you can do something like this to cover Windows and Linux:

```
unix {
     INCLUDEPATH +=  ../Lib
     LIBS += -L../Lib -lLib
}

win32 {
     INCLUDEPATH += ../Lib
     LIBS += ../Lib.lib
}
```

Comment: No, that didn't help. It succesfully touches liblib.a file to which a lib compiles and generates the same message.

Comment: what i prefer is to set (export) an environment variable which contains the absolute path to the project directory. Then I use it in .pro files for include paths and lib paths:
`INCLUDEPATH += $(PROJECT_HOME)/include
LIBS += -L$(PROJECT_HOME)/lib
LIBS += -lsomeLib`. This way you dont have problems with relative paths in pro files